# Sequelize migration to enact onDelete cascade

Tags: sequelize.js

I am working with a code base and I need to enact cascading deletion. The code is organized in a way that is different from the docs. In the models folder, there is an index file and an init-models file. The init-models file has this structure ...

```
var _myModel = require("./myModel");
var _parentModel = require("./parentModel");

function initModels(sequelize) {
    var myModel = _myModel(sequelize, DataTypes);
    var parentModel = _parentModel(sequelize, DataTypes);
    myModel.belongsTo(parentModel, { as: "parentModel", foreignKey: "parentModel_id"});
    parentModel.hasMany(myModel, { as: "myModel", foreignKey: "parentModel_id"});
}
```

Adjusting these to include onDelete : "cascade" is simple, but the question is : "Do I need a migration to accomplish this?" If so, how do I write that migration?